# Hibernate 5 Infinispan :java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, infinispan

I tried all I could find in internet excluding JBoss log from dependency and all, and I still get the `NoSuchMethodError`.

I'm using `hibernate-infinispan 5.0.0.Final` with `Spring 4.3.1`.

Any idea and help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Stack trace and dependency tree is as follows:

```
**Stacktrace:**

    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        at org.hibernate.internal.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries(NamedQueryRepository.java:149) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:764) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:495) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:502) [spring-orm-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:486) [spring-orm-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        ... 37 more
```

Dependency Tree :

```
    [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli)
    [INFO] com.macys:vendor-hierarchy-service:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
    [INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
    [INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile
    [INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-web:jar:1.2.3:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-spring:jar:1.2.3:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-all:jar:1.2.3:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.apache.shiro:shiro-guice:jar:1.2.3:compile
    [INFO] |     +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:r09:compile
    [INFO] |     +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
    [INFO] |     |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
    [INFO] |     |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
    [INFO] |     \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings:jar:3.0:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile
    [INFO] |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.5.0:compile
    [INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
    [INFO] +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:jar:1.17.1:compile
    [INFO] |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.17.1:compile
    [INFO] |     \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.17.1:compile
    [INFO] |        +- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
    [INFO] |        \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.17.1:compile
    [INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:jar:2.22.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.22.2:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.22.2:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.22.2:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.22.2:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.22.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:2.2.4:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.web:javax.el:jar:2.2.4:compile
    [INFO] |  \- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
    [INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile
    [INFO] +- org.infinispan:infinispan-core:jar:7.2.1.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.infinispan:infinispan-commons:jar:7.2.1.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.jgroups:jgroups:jar:3.6.2.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling-osgi:jar:1.4.10.Final:compile
    [INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-infinispan:jar:5.0.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.rhq.helpers:rhq-pluginAnnotations:jar:3.0.4:compile
    [INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
    [INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.2.2.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.02:compile
    [INFO] |  \- xom:xom:jar:1.0:compile
    [INFO] |     +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
    [INFO] |     \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.6.0:compile
    [INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
    [INFO] +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:4.2.0.GA_CP01:compile
    [INFO] +- com.macys.mst.main.iapi:main-iapi-java:jar:0.3.6.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.0-beta9:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.0-beta9:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
    [INFO] |  \- com.lmax:disruptor:jar:3.2.0:compile
    [INFO] \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change the `org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile` to `org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.Final:compile`. The [problematic commit](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logging/commit/6024badef6ff612cb48d7e4dfd7c8af5919ccceb) was introduced in `3.2.0.Final`

Also please make sure that your platform does not provide this jar in version >= `3.2.0`.

Alternatively upgrade Infinispan to the latest stable version (8.2.3.Final).

Comment: I dont think there is 3.1.0.final version , I see 3.1.0.GA version available which i tried but still giving the same error.

Comment: Yes, you are right... Could you please create a really small reproducer and share it though Github? I would like to have a look at it...

Answer (score 0):

Infinispan uses JBoss Logging. You will need this as a runtime dependency. Version 5.0 may be before the "uber" jars where they started shadowing their dependencies inside the inifinispan jar.

Comment: 5.0 is infinspan-hibernate version. Infinispan version 7.2.1 is what being used here. I excluded jboss -logging from infinispan dependency aswell , still no luck